# How to get the current time for a specific timezone?

Tags: magento-1.9, zend-framework

I have tried doing this using Zend, by `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');`, 
but this will change the time zone for all of the future `Zend_Date` calls (if I am not mistaken). 
I just need to assign the current time in Copenhagen to one variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimezone('Europe/Copenhagen'));
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```